# How to get blog-id of an MU site from functions.php

Tags: theme-development, multisite

How can one determine, from functions.php, the blog-id of the site (or alternately, the path to the media directory)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the current site, you can use the `$current_site` global variable and look at the blog_id member variable, e.g. `$current_site->blog_id`

Comment: Thanks mtekk, I've updated my question with your answer and my script.

Comment: I can't get $current_site->blog_id to echo anything

Comment: Inside a function you'll need to globalise the var else it's outside the scope of the function.. ie. `global $current_site;`

Comment: You'll need to globalise it, as t31os said, even if you are calling it just in the functions.php file.

Comment: FYI `$GLOBALS['current_site']->blog_id` will work without using the `globals` keyword first. It also has the advantage of being clearly global everywhere you use it.